# what would be the Impact of using Multiple sites in same VPC on AWS platform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ddos, amazon-vpc

I have a site running on four server inside of a VPC on aws platform. My question is  would their be any impact on site if I host another website on four new server in the same VPC considering their is no relation between the sites  ?
would  DDOS/DOS attack on any of the site will reduce the the performance of other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really needs to be asked of Amazon support, but yes, there would be an effect. Machines in the same VPC do share infrastructure, namely IGWs, which could get overloaded during a DDoS. This could lead to poor performance for other non-related sites hosted out of the same VPC.